# Security camera feed storage on remote servers

Tags: http, websocket, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

What are the suggested latest technologies to build a security surveillance system?

This system will have 100+ cameras uploading live streams to cloud servers for storage and post-processing.

Any suggested architecture along with technologies will be helpful to read and to do some experiments.

Comment: worked on something similar a while ago for a client using local IOT devices as ground encoders and sending streams to Azure Media Services for storage and processing using AzureML tools. not cheap at that sort of scale.